# How to create a cross browser compatible full background image/

Tags: jquery, background, css

I have spent a few hours surfing the net and going through some web development books to find an answer. I have an image of size `1920x1289`. This image is to be used for the background. I want the image to be fixed, remain centered, fill the visible browser area and not cause any scroll bars. I have come across solutions that use pure css such as `background-size:cover;` and b`ackground-size:100% auto;`.
I am familiar with CSS but not jquery. I came across the following script:

http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/

My question is which option is the "best" for my purpose. If I go for the jquery will it cause any performance issues. I will be using this method for a responsive website. I specifically wanted to use the background property instead of an img property for semantics and also clean coding. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It completely depends on what is your vision with the project you are working on. If you want just the background image to fill the screen then roXon answer is enough, but for more feature support as I haven't gone through the library yet. But as far as you are pointing to performance issues, I would say jquery won't make yourwebpage slow as it is the fastest javascript engine - prooved.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        height: 100%;
        background: url('images/someimage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

This will resize properly in all browsers.

Comment: all browsers ? Does that includes IE8 ?

Comment: Not exactly sure about IE8.  I know it works in IE9.  Give it a try in developers mode (F12) and select IE8.

Answer (score 1):

if you're not afraid to say 'goodbye' to IE7,8 you can simply use
 **CSS3 `background-size`** (and some background-position center trickery) :

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uyamof/21/)

```
<div id="bg"></div>
```

```
#bg{
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url(bg.jpg) 50% / cover;
}
```

Comment: Note: you might need to add  negative z-index for #bg element, otherwise due to absolute positioning it might cover your other elements. At least it was happening for me, until I added negative z-index to it.

Comment: @hanazair you might but I'd rather suggest to keep it like it is, you simply set to your page container what you should set, and that's `position`: see [this for an example](http://jsbin.com/pajuri/1/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously css are better option than jquery as they are bit faster. Use css3 if you dont worry about older browsers.
But if you want to do for all browser use jquery, but dont add an extra plugin to achive it.
Instead you can try little trick by not setting image as a background and using img tag itself.

Here the code

HTML

```
 <img src="your img source" id="backgroundImg"/>
```

css

```
#backgroundImg{
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:-100; //so it will not overlay on other elements
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
var backgroundResizeFun=function(){
$('#backgroundImg').css({
width:$(window).width()+'px',
height:$(window).height()+'px'
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
backgroundResizeFun();
$(window).resize(function(){
backgroundResizeFun();
});
});
```

Comment: I am a complete noob to jquery. How do I attatch the jquery code so it works?

Comment: Jquery is just a library of javascript. So you need to include it on your page either by downloading a copy of jquery.js file from jquery site or use google hosted library

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

And just write all your jquery code inside script tag as you are doing for javascript.